# Avoiding quotes around row of string data with csv.writer

Tags: python, string, csv

I am trying to write a row of strings (it's the header row) to a csv file using csv.writer as follows:

```
mbfile=open(pathtodata + "mbsensors.csv", "ab")
writer=csv.writer(mbfile)

writer.writerow(["ESReadings"])

i=1
tempstring='DateTime'

while i<=numsensors:
    tempstring=tempstring+','+ "%02d"%i +'.Cooked'
    i=i+1

print tempstring
writer.writerow([tempstring])
mbfile.close
```

(I don't know why that first row has indented - it's not like that in my code).

Using Python 2.7.3 in Linux.

writer.writerow(["ESReadings"]) writes fine, without surrounding double quotes.

print tempstring displays on screen as expected.

writer.writerow([tempstring]) writes fine, except it has double quotes around it.

I am importing this data into a Windows program and it won't like the quotes, how can I avoid them?

Comment: You should use `for i in xrange(1,numsensors+1):` instead of `while`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The csv writer thinks that you're trying to write a single entry, which is why it's putting quotes around the full string.  You should pass the row as a list (or some other iterable) of strings, and let the writer insert the commas.  Something like this:

```
tempstring=['DateTime']
while i<=numsensors:
 tempstring.append("%02d"%i +'.Cooked')
 i=i+1
 print tempstring
 writer.writerow(tempstring)
```

Comment: Brilliant, worked perfectly.  Thanks for answering so promptly.